# How to add every byte read from a stream to a checksum

Tags: c++

I'm writing a program to read a specific type of file. The file is structured like a tree, so I'm creating a tree of objects to mirror the structure of the file.

The problem I'm running in to is that any branch of the tree may optionally be verified by a checksum. This includes branches that are children of a branch that's also got a checksum.

My original plan was to keep a stack of active checksum objects, each of which would be responsible for the checksum of one branch. Every time I read from the stream, I would have to remember to send that data to each object in the stack, so each one could update their internal checksum. But I'm reading from the stream in quite a few places, so that strategy is getting *real* old, *real* fast.

What's the easiest way to be able to look at each byte read from a stream in one place? I'm thinking of subclassing `istream`, would that work?

Comment: Can you clarify whether a children branch content affect parent branch checksum? What is stopping you from storing checksums in each tree node?

Comment: If there was one massive array (or `std::string` or `std::vector`) of all of the bytes in the file, each note could have an index and a length (or a `std::string_view`) that encompassed everything below it you'd get what you wanted with minimal fuss and no copying.

Comment: It is fairly easy to inject something in the input stream by subclassing `std::streambuf` and then constructing a `std::istream` that uses the subclassed `std::streambuf`. However this does not really expose the logical calls to formatted input operations, one at a time, but only the larger buffer fills. I'm afraid you'll have to rip out `std::istream` from your existing code, replace it with your own abstract input sink, which uses the real `std::istream` to read from, and then calculates the checksum as it carries the data back to the code that asked for it.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Yes, child node content does affect the parent's (and the parent's parent's, etc.) checksum.

Comment: @user4581301 These are rather large files, so I'd rather not slurp the whole file into RAM at once. But that's not a hard requirement, so I'll have to test to see if its feasible.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's kind of what I was afraid of. Well, better to discover it now!

Comment: @HiddenWindshield that's (also) what I was afraid of. Brute force rarely scales. When you can use it, though, it's easy and you're done.

Comment: *Every time I read from the stream, I would have to remember to send that data to each object in the stack... is getting real old, real fast.* - Ok, why don't you have a unified function or class that handles reading and updating the stack at the same time?

Comment: Then you are traversing that tree from the wrong end? You should start reading from the leafs and up the tree. That way you will always have a sub-checksum which will allow you to have a correct parent checksum.

Comment: @selbie Yeah, I think that's what I'm going to have to do.

Comment: @IgorLevicki Unfortunately, the organization of the file prevents me from doing that.

Comment: This is a strange way to do Merkle trees. Are you sure you are supposed to checksum the entire bytestream for the child and not just a digest  of the child?